# How to change the default browser delete confirmation box

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

I want to change the default browser confirmation box to use the dialog box giving by jquery ui library. Is they an easy way for this to be do

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily enough using the [confirmation example](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/modal-confirmation.html) as a starting point. I recommend that you create a `confirm` utility function to display one of these confirmation dialogs, so you can easily call into the code from your application.

One big difference is that the default `confirm` will block your JavaScript code until the user clicks a button. The jQuery UI dialog will not block. That means that you need to pass callback functions to the dialog to execute code when the user presses `Yes` or `No` (or whatever you call the confirmation buttons).

Comment: I cant get it right checked out the documentation but i cannot prevent it from using the default

Comment: am i suppose to assign a selector to the link